# Assign bash value from value in specific line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like:

```
>ref_frame=1 
TPGIRYQYNVLPQGWKGSPAIFQSSMTKILEPFRKQNPDIVIYQYMDDLYVGSD
>ref_frame=2 
HQGLDISTMCFHRDGKDHQQYSKVA*QKS*SLLENKIQT*LSINTWMICM*DLT
>ref_frame=3 
TRD*ISVQCASTGMERITSNIPK*HDKNLRAF*KTKSRHSYLSIHG*FVCRI*
>test_3_2960_3_frame=1 
TPGIRYQYNVLPQGWKGSPAIFQSSMTKILEPSRKQNPDIVIYQYMDDLYVGSD
```

I want to assign a bash variable so that `echo $variable` gives `test_3_2960`

The line/row that I want to assign the variable to will always be line 7. How can I accomplish this using bash?

so far I have:

```
variable=`cat file.txt | awk 'NR==7'`
```

`echo $variable` = `>test_3_2960_3_frame=1`

Comment: What part of the line do you want to extract? First three elements separated by underscores?

Comment: Hi, I want the variable to give: test_3_2960

Comment: That's clear, but what do you want to get for inputs like `blah_2_2345_5_abc_def=12`?

Comment: I think blah2_2_2345 would work. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ variable=$(sed -En '7s/>(([^_]*_){2}[0-9]+).*/\1/p' input_file)
$ echo "$variable"
test_3_2960
```

Answer (score 2):

No pipes needed here...

```
$: variable=$(awk -F'[>_]' 'NR==7{ OFS="_"; print $2, $3, $4; exit; }' file)
$: echo $variable
test_3_2960
```

`-F` is using either `>` or `_` as field separators, so your data starts in field 2.
`OFS="_"` sets the Output Field Separator, but you could also just use "_" instead of commas.
`exit` keeps it from wasting time bothering to read beyond line 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to continue with `awk`

```
   $ variable=$(awk 'NR==7' file.txt | awk -F "[>_]" '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4}')  
   $ echo $variable  
   test_3_2960
```

Comment: You can do all in one pass `'NR==7 {print $2 "_" $3 "_" $4}'` and maybe play with OFS... Anyway, welcome SO @mrrobot-viewsource